# How to display image in TCPDF using BLOB value

Tags: php, mysql, tcpdf

TCPDF: How can I display the image in TCPDF using the BLOB value retrieved from MySQL Database?

Comment: Generate temporary image in a writable folder on the filesystem and import the image in the PDF. When imported, delete the image.

Comment: @MartyMcVry - Not required with TCPDF. The OP just didn't read the docs ;-)

Comment: @MartyMcVry after you delete the image, would you still view the image in the PDF?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [example #9 - Image()](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_009.phps):

```
// Example of Image from data stream ('PHP rules')
$imgdata = base64_decode('iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABwAAAASCAMAAAB/2U7WAAAABlBMVEUAAAD///+l2Z/dAAAASUlEQVR4XqWQUQoAIAxC2/0vXZDrEX4IJTRkb7lobNUStXsB0jIXIAMSsQnWlsV+wULF4Avk9fLq2r8a5HSE35Q3eO2XP1A1wQkZSgETvDtKdQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');

// The '@' character is used to indicate that follows an image data stream and not an image file name
$pdf->Image('@'.$imgdata);
```

The [API documentation for `Image()`](http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#a714c2bee7d6b39d4d6d304540c761352) explains it in more detail:

> **$file**
>     (string) Name of the file containing the image or a '@' character
>   followed by the image data string. To link an image without embedding
>   it on the document, set an asterisk character before the URL (i.e.:
>   `*http://www.example.com/image.jpg`).

Comment: looks like the base64_decode() might not be necessary.

Comment: @Chen PHP strings can certainly hold binary data (and this same example does so) but most text editors are not appropriate to edit binary data ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As already answered by Álvaro González TCPDF you could pass an image blob to `TCPDF::Image()` but this has some major drawback:

TCPDF image caching is not working for image blobs. Therefore TCPDF consumes much more memory if you pass the same image multiple times.

If you pass an image blob TCPDF writes that one to a temporary file. But it does not check if the same image blob has already been provided. So it will write new temporary files even if you pass the same image again. This does not only cause unnecessary IO but also breaks image caching build into tcpdf.

Long story short: If you use an image multiple times do not pass an image blob to tcpdf. Save it to a temporary file and pass that one.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out many **php TCPDF Library** users are mostly in a dilemma about from mysqli database let follow the following quick guide

1. get your TCPDF configuration ready, your text editor
2. get working
3. open your php file which will be use to load the pdf document generated
4. include the follow

> 

5. establish a database connection as follows

> $sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['user']."'";
>   $query = $conn->query($sql); $user=(!empty($user['photo'])) ?
>   'images/'.$user['photo'] : 'images/profile.jpg' $user =
>   $query->fetch_assoc();

6. include all the pdf parameters to set up the pdf environment on your browser

   // create new PDF document

> $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT,
>   true, 'UTF-8', false);
>
> // set document information $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
>   $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni'); $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 009');
>   $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial'); $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF,
>   example, test, guide');
>
> // set default header data $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO,
>   PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 009', PDF_HEADER_STRING);
>
> // set header and footer fonts
>   $pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '',
>   PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN)); $pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA,
>   '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
>
> // set default monospaced font
>   $pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
>
> // set margins $pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP,
>   PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT); $pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
>   $pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
>
> // set auto page breaks $pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE,
>   PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
>
> // set image scale factor $pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
>
> // set some language-dependent strings (optional) if
>   (@file_exists(dirname(**FILE**).'/lang/eng.php')) {
>       require_once(dirname(**FILE**).'/lang/eng.php');
>       $pdf->setLanguageArray($l); }
>
> // -------------------------------------------------------------------
>
> // add a page $pdf->AddPage();
>
> // set JPEG quality $pdf->setJPEGQuality(75);

7. call you image parameters

> $x = 165; $y = 28; $w = 50; $h = 50; // Image example with resizing
>   $pdf->Image('images/'.$voter['photo']."",$x, $y, $w, $h,  'JPG','');

8. $x means padding horizontally while $y stands for padding vertically , $w means width and $h means height respectively.
9. set your output

> $pdf->Output('adding_from_Myqli_database.pdf', 'I');

10. close your php tag with

> ?>

11. hope you have learn from perhaps your problem is solved